# Does Violet also stubbornly refuse to kill people in the novel [Violet Evergarden]?

Tags: violet-evergarden

In the anime (episode 12) Violet was fighting against the anti-peace rebels on a train but was restrained and almost killed (if not for Dietfried killing these rebels) due to her refusal to kill them.
I’m not sure if I remember it correctly, but the following event that led to the rebels almost achieving their goal of detonating the bridge (which would have killed most passengers on the train) probably wouldn’t have been so close to succeeding if only Violet had killed the rebels right from the beginning of her fight.

While I really liked the story, this single scene has left quite a big shadow. But from what I’ve scraped together on the internet, it seems that in the novel Violet doesn’t have such pacifistic tendencies. While she only fought barehanded in the anime (except in the flashbacks), she’s apparently seen fighting with weapons multiple times in the novel.

Am I right in the conclusion that in the novel Violet is willing to kill people if she needs to (i.e. to prevent other people or herself from getting killed)?
The train scene also seems to be quite different from the anime as Gilbert is supposed to make his entrance there. So, does the scene where Violet refuses to kill her enemies also happen in the novel?